# handshake error in connecting SQL server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I got this error while connecting to local DB

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Help

Comment: You're using a self-signed certificate, and your client is rejected it...

Comment: can you teach me how to solve this problem, I already research it in the web and I can't find the right solution. I already check my sql server client network utility and it seems the force protocol is already unchecked.

Comment: Sorry, but this is off topic for the site. it's not a programming question - it's server configuration. try serverfault.com